# Sample size from proportions

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable that follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$. If the maximum error of the $90$% confidence interval is $0.2$, what sample size is required under the following scenarios

(i) $p$ is unknown.

(ii) $p \geq 0.8$

My attempt:

(i)

As $p$ is unknown the sample size needed is:

$$n = \frac{z_{\alpha/2}^2 \cdot 0.25}{E^2} = \frac{1.6448536^2 \cdot 0.25}{0.2^2} \approx 16.9096$$

We take the upper integer $17$.

(ii)

$p\geq 0.8 \implies 1-p \leq 0.2 \implies p(1-p) \leq 0.16$

The sample size needed here is:

$$n = \frac{z_{\alpha/2}^2 \cdot 0.16}{E^2} = \frac{1.6448536^2 \cdot 0.16}{0.2^2} \approx 10.8222$$

We take the upper integer $11$.

Are these correct? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: With sample size $n\approx 10$ and $p > .8$ I would not trust either the normal approximation or the asymptotic Wald interval that lead to your key formula.

Comment: @BruceET So what would you suggest?

Comment: Anticipated this question. See my Answer for one approach. // If this is a hwk exercise specifically for Wald CIs, what you have done is probably what is expected. Your text would not be the only one to recommend this formula to get $n$ for given $p$ and $E,$ in spite of its deficiencies. // But if you are planning to do a serious project and want to be reasonably sure to have large enough $n,$ then you should do something like what is in my Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reliable CIs for $n = 11$ and $p<.2$ or $p>.8$ should not be based on
the formula for margin of error $E$ you are using. You should use some
kind of exact binomial Ci.

For example, in R, the procedure `binom.test` makes a style of CI with
reliable coverage probability. It uses exact binomial CDFs instead of
normal approximation. (See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) on binomial confidence
intervals for several styles of intervals.)

Here are two confidence intervals based on $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=11,p=.8).$
They have margins of error $E = 0.247$ and $0.275.$ respectively.

```
set.seed(2021)
CI = binom.test(rbinom(1,11,.8), 11)$conf.int 
CI; diff(CI);  diff(CI)/2
[1] 0.4822441 0.9771688
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
[1] 0.4949247  # length of CI
[1] 0.2474623  $ E

CI = binom.test(rbinom(1,11,.8), 11)$conf.int 
CI; diff(CI);  diff(CI)/2
[1] 0.3902574 0.9397823
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
[1] 0.5495248
[1] 0.2747624
```

In a simulation of 100,000 95% CIs with $n=11, p=0.8,$ the average
margin of error was $0.24,$ not $0.20.$

```
set.seed(410)
E = replicate(10^5, diff(binom.test(rbinom(1,11,.8), 11)$conf.int)/2)
mean(E)
[1] 0.2418242
```

Using $n = 20$ would probably be better:

```
set.seed(410)
E = replicate(10^5, diff(binom.test(rbinom(1,20,.8), 20)$conf.int)/2)
mean(E)
[1] 0.1834582

hist(E, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Comment: While this is pretty interesting, I haven't actually covered a binomial approach. All I know comes from the book Probability and Statistical Inference 10th edition chapter 7.4, which only deals with the normal approach...

Comment: Maybe that's Hogg and Tanis. When the _first_ edition of this book appeared, the deficiencies of the Wald CI were not fully appreciated. Maybe 10e mentions Agresti-Cooil CIs which are better for small and moderate sample sizes, but the A-C CIs don't give such a nice formula to get n from E and p. // While you're in this course, I recommend you follow the book and lectures. But if you get into planning and analyzing experiments later, make sure you use the the best available methods.